# Find specific JSON key and return its value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON from an API which I am logging in the console.
This is easy for something like the id where I can do this...

```
let movieID = out.id;
console.log(movieID)
```

But how can I also return the 'name' of the person whose job is specifically 'Director' from JSON example like this? Basically I need to do something like 'if someone has the JOB of DIRECTOR, log their name to the console.

```
{
    "id": 37291,
    "credits": {
        "crew": [
            {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "job": "Producer"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mary Jones",
                "job": "Director"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through the array and check their job...

Comment: Yes, I need to know how to loop through the array to check their job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of the crew, like you described above. Then find the first entry in that list where the job equals "Director" and put it in a variable:

```
let director = out.credits.crew.find(member => member.job == "Director");
```

You can then log the data, as you did for the movie itself.

Comment: This works, but it gives me all of the data under the Directors name instead of just the name itself.

Comment: Try `console.log(director.name)` to print the director's name

Comment: That worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do literally what you asked which was to console log out the names

```
credits.crew.foreach((crewMember) => {
    if (crewMember.job == 'Director') {
      console.log(crewMember.name)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore:

```
_.filter(credits.crew, (key) => key.job === 'Director')
```

That will give you all the keys with that value. Trust me you should use underscore or lodash because objects can get super tricky and it saves you a ton of time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter 

Reaching for a library now for a filter function alone is probably overkill. A lot of what loadash and underscore provided when they were created now have native equivalents

Comment: @aroundtheworld Some of the best javascript developers in the industry have recommended me these libraries for years. People working directly with Facebook. So no random guy from the internet is gonna convince me otherwise. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: `recommended me these libraries for years.` << that was all I was getting at, and native browser JS spec is updated over time